# How do I replace an existing release with a GitHub action

Tags: automation, release, github-actions

I have a project where I'd like to be able to automate releases using Github actions. The process is relatively straightforward, using the `actions/create-release@v1` and `actions/upload-release-asset@v1` actions.

But in certain circumstances (testing, re-releases when my upstream project makes changes) I would like to be able to automate *replacing* an existing release. Of course, I can do this manually by deleting the release from Github, and running the release action again, but is it possible to automate this? I know that the "best" approach is to create a new release, but in some cases I'm tied to my upstream release numbering, and that's not possible.

Alternatively, is it possible to check if a release exists (and get its "upload asset" URL again)?

I've used Github Actions a bit, but I haven't really used the GitHub API - so if the answer is "Use the GitHub API to do this" it would be good to have a bit more detail about how I can use the API from within an action.